# Android: Play Video from download URL

Tags: android

i know there is VideoView can play given stream URL. but is that possible to play video that is from download URL?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: What is a "download URL"?

Comment: @CommonsWare link which is direct download file from browser to folder instead of streaming on web browser.

Comment: It's gonna end up being downloaded then played ..it's not gonna be streamed

Answer (score 1):

it can be other option , playing video in Default Player

```
  String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl("video url");          
  String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
  Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  mediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("video url"), mimeType);
  startActivity(mediaIntent);
```

Comment: Ya this work for default player. Seem like after donwload whole file then only start playing. is that possible to do this with VideoView?

Comment: Most of the video application will stream

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    String url = "Type your url here ";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
         VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
           myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
           myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
           myVideoView.requestFocus();

           myVideoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```